# jquery hover and click events returning multiple objects

Tags: jquery, events, iteration, stoppropagation

I have various elements with the same class.

I want to have events for all of the elements but i only want to gather information from the first element like so:

```
elements[i].before = css($(elements[i].handle).first());
```

When I hover over the elements it is giving me an alert per element... Great!... but the css() function is returning all 3 of the elements css even though i am using first()... The css function is:

```
function css(a){
        var sheets = document.styleSheets, o = {};
        for(var i in sheets) {
            var rules = sheets[i].rules || sheets[i].cssRules;
            for(var r in rules) {
                if(a.is(rules[r].selectorText)) {
                    o = $.extend(o, css2json(rules[r].style), css2json(a.attr('style')));
                }
            }
        }
        return o;
    }

    function css2json(css){
        var s = {};
        if(!css) return s;
        if(css instanceof CSSStyleDeclaration) {
            for(var i in css) {
                if((css[i]).toLowerCase) {
                    s[(css[i]).toLowerCase()] = (css[css[i]]);
                }
            }
        } else if(typeof css == "string") {
            css = css.split("; ");          
            for (var i in css) {
                var l = css[i].split(": ");
                s[l[0].toLowerCase()] = (l[1]);
            };
        }
        return s;
    }
```

I have tried:

```
if(event.target != this){
    return true;
}
event.stopPropagation();
```

to no avail... Full source here:

```
    var options = [
        '#content',
        'h5'              
    ];
    var elements = [];
    var current_item = '';


            for(a in options){
                elements[a] = {
                    'handle':  options[a], 
                    'before': '',
                    'after': ''
                };

                $(elements[a].handle).attr('index', a);

                $(elements[a].handle).hover(
                    function(event){ 
                        if(event.target != this){
                            return true;
                        }
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        var i = get_index(this); 
                        elements[i].before = css($(elements[i].handle).first());
                        $(this).css({
                            border: '1px dashed red',
                            padding: '5px'
                        });
                    },
                    function(){
                        var i = get_index(this); 
                        $(this).css(elements[i].before);
                    }
                );

                $(elements[a].handle).click(
                    function(){
                        if(event.target != this){
                            return true;
                        }
                        event.stopPropagation();
                        var i = get_index(this); 
                        alert(i);
                        $('#current_item').val(options[i]);     
                    }
                );
            }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Check out

.first() http://api.jquery.com/first/

and

:first http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/

depending on your needs.